# Removing duplicate sub-elements

Tags: matlab, signals

I have a vector `a1` and want to get an output `a2`. Basically, I should identify the starting index of numbers, keep the first value and replace the repeating elements as `NaN`.

```
a1=[-2 -2 -2 -2 NaN NaN NaN -3 -3 -3 -3 NaN NaN -2 -2 -2 NaN -3 -3 NaN NaN 1 1 1 1 NaN NaN 4 4 4 NaN NaN 3 3 3 NaN];

a2=[-2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN -2 NaN NaN NaN -3 NaN NaN NaN 1 NaN NaN NaN 4 NaN NaN NaN NaN 3 NaN NaN NaN];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you format is exactly as you've shown (NaN's in between consecutive numbers), then the following should work.

First identity the indices where the NaN's start and end

```
inds = [1 diff(isnan(a1))] ~= 0;
```

Now ininitialize `a2` and copy over relevant values from `a1`

```
a2 = nan(size(a1));
a2(inds) = a1(inds);
```